# Intput/Output to QLabel?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like my input from the keyboard to be sent to a QLabel. But I dont want just to put the text in it as label->setText("") but instead to see every letter from the keyboard to appear immediately in the label. Any ideas? I just need someone to point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the source of the text input?

Comment: Can you just do `label->setText(label->text() + characterFromKeyboard)` on each keyboard event?

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly possible. But you can create a class inheriting `QLabel` and reimplement `keyPressEvent` to handle this manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a QLineEdit and make it read only and use stylesheets to hide borders etc...

Have a look at the stylesheet info here

[Qt Stylesheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html)